# Python, Excel and Pandas: drop rows based on multiple criterias

Tags: python, excel, pandas

First of all, I know similar questions have been asked in the past, but none of them apply to my use case, not I know Pandas enough to get there on my own. So, I have 2 spreadsheets (xlsx), let's call them file 1 and file 2

File1:

| ID | IP | Name | Comments | OS | Title | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active |
| 2 | `127.0.0.1` | Something else |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed |
| 3 | `127.0.0.1` | New one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active |

File2:

| ID | IP | Name | Comments | OS | Title | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed |
| 5 | `127.0.0.1` | Uh-oh |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active |

I'm merging these 2 files in Python, with Pandas:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')
#I just need a column with the file name, hence these variables
file1 = "file1.xlsx"
file2 = "file2.xlsx"
df1 = df1.sort_values('ID')
#Adds a new column with the file name
df1["File"] = file1
df2 = df2.sort_values('ID')
#Adds a new column with the file name
df2["File"] = file2
dfs = [df1, df2]
#Black magic to merge the 2 files into 1
df_diff = pd.concat(dfs).drop_duplicates(keep=False, subset=['IP', 'Name', 'Comments', 'ID', 'Title', 'Status'])
df_diff = df_diff.drop(df_diff[])
df_diff.to_excel(r'file3.xlsx')
```

And this is the resulting file:

| ID | IP | Name | Comments | OS | Title | Status | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 2 | `127.0.0.1` | Something else |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 1 |
| 3 | `127.0.0.1` | New one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 1 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 5 | `127.0.0.1` | Uh-oh |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 2 |

As you can see, in the new file there is a new column indicating what file that row comes from (row File). Now, I would like Pandas to check for the following condition:

any row present in file 1 only, with the Status set to fixed.

I would like to drop from file 3 any rows matching the above condition, so that I end up with the following table:

| ID | IP | Name | Comments | OS | Title | Status | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 5 | `127.0.0.1` | Uh-oh |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 2 |

How could I achieve this? As an addendum, I would also like the following condition to be met:

any row present in both file, with the only difference being in file 1 Status is Active and in file 2 Status is Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The first condition is actually pretty simple but a bit unintuitive. Selecting based on multiple criteria works pretty much the same as with a single criterium, but you just add a binary & and put every criterium between parentheses:

```
df[ (df['File'] == 'File 1') & (df['Status'] == 'Fixed') ]
```

It has to be '&' and not 'and'. The second condition can be met in a similar way:

```
IDs_file1_active = df[ (df['File'] == 'File 1') & (df['Status'] == 'Active') ]['ID']
```

selects the ID of every Active entry from file 1. Now you can selects the rows with their IDs from the original table:

```
file1_active = df[ df['ID'].isin(IDs_file1_active) ]
```

and apply the second condition:

```
file1_active [ (file1_active ['File'] == 'File 2') & (file1_active ['Status'] == 'Fixed') ]
```

This should do what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry to ask, where would
    df[ (df['File'] == 'File 1') & (df['Status'] == 'Fixed') ]
go into my code? I'm very new to Pandas

Comment: Wherever you want to select those rows really, so after merging the two tables I guess.

Comment: Ok, your answer for the first condition works like a charm. The second condition, however, does not filter anything. Bear in mind that the ID column gets created by Pandas concat (I think), it's not part of the original 2 files.

Comment: I wrote my answer under the impression that the merged pandas dataframe would be the one to work with. If that's the case you should apply this after creating the DF with the ID column. Just to be clear, the IDs_file1_active line just selects the IDs of the entries that meet you condition, the actual entries that meet both conditions are only selected in the last line.

Comment: Problem is, the column called ID gets created by the concat functions, and does not have a header; I've called it ID for sake of clarity in my aswer. I cannot even find a way to rename it right after the concatenation, as Pandas thinks that column [0] is IP, and completely ignores that ID column.

Comment: Riiight, I get it now . Could it be that the ID column is actually the index of the df? In that case you could do df['ID'] = df.index to make it a column, after which the above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditionals for selecting. To exclude use tilde

```
cond=(df['File']=='File 1') & (df['Status'] =='Fixed')
df[~cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your last dataset is call de `df`

So, you can try the following code

```
mask = (df["File"]=="File 1") & (df["Status"]=="Fixed")
df = df[~mask]

df
```

| ID | IP | Name | Comments | OS | Title | Status | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 1 | `127.0.0.1` | Something |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 1 |
| 4 | `127.0.0.1` | Yet another one |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Fixed | File 2 |
| 5 | `127.0.0.1` | Uh-oh |  | Windows 3.11 | Title 1 | Active | File 2 |